# Is it possible to catch a foreign key violation in postgres

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2

I'm trying to insert data into a table which has a foreign key constraint. If there is a constraint violation in a row that I'm inserting, I want to chuck that data away.

The issue is that postgres returns an error every time I violate the constraint. Is it possible for me to have some statement in my insert statement like 'ON FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINT DO NOTHING'?

EDIT:

This is the query that I'm trying to do, where info is a dict:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO event (case_number_id, date, \
session, location, event_type, worker, result) VALUES \
(%(id_number)s, %(date)s, %(session)s, \
%(location)s, %(event_type)s, %(worker)s, %(result)s) ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING", info)
```

It errors out when there is a foreign key violation

Comment: That's what the error is for. You could just silently ignore the error in the code calling the insert.

Comment: how would I do that?

Comment: That depends on the calling code, and the language it's written in

Comment: python cursor (psycog2) with raw postgres

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're only inserting a single row at a time, you can create a [savepoint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-savepoint.html) before the insert and [rollback](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-rollback-to.html) to it when the insert fails (or [release it](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-release-savepoint.html) when the insert succeeds).

<s>For Postgres 9.5 or later, you can use [`INSERT ... ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT) which does what it says.  You can *also* write `ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE SET column = value...`, which will automagically convert your insert into an update of the row you are conflicting with (this functionality is sometimes called "upsert").</s>

This does not work because OP is dealing with a *foreign key* constraint rather than a *unique* constraint.  In that case, you can most easily use the savepoint method I described earlier, but for multiple rows it may prove tedious.  If you need to insert multiple rows at once, it should be reasonably performant to split them into multiple insert statements, *provided* you are not [working in autocommit mode](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ecpg-sql-set-autocommit.html), all inserts occur in one transaction, and you are not inserting a very large number of rows.

Sometimes, you really do need multiple inserts in a single statement, because the round-trip overhead of talking to your database plus the cost of having savepoints on every insert is simply too high.  In this case, there are a number of imperfect approaches.  Probably the *least bad* is to build a nested query which selects your data and joins it against the other table, something like this:

```
INSERT INTO table_A (column_A, column_B, column_C)
SELECT A_rows.*
FROM VALUES (...) AS A_rows(column_A, column_B, column_C)
JOIN table_B ON A_rows.column_B = table_B.column_B;
```

Comment: on conflict do nothing is not helping me. I already had it, but the integrity error still occurs

Comment: yup, just posted the query!

Comment: @chris: I need the error message and the Postgres version as well.

Comment: psql (9.5.3). Will re--run the script to get the error message, give me a second.